# Sample code does not work when interacting with component states [video.js with react]

Tags: reactjs, video.js

### Description

When trying to update a state in any event related to the player, the video disappears.  https://codesandbox.io/s/videojs-react-hooks-example-forked-17bx0?file=/src/VideoJsPlayer.js

### Steps to reproduce

Explain in detail the exact steps necessary to reproduce the issue.

1. Instantiate the videojs, ex: `player = videjs(reference, options);`
2. add a listener, ex: `player.on('play', onPlayerListener);`
3. In the listener trigger any state update.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to initialize the player and its listeners only during the first "component mount" you should exclude `[props]` from `useEffect`. Just transform `[props]` into `[]` and everything should work fine.